# How can I change the root folder of my mPDF Output()?

Tags: php, mpdf

How can I change the root folder of my mPDF `Output()`?

I need a filename that is taken from a variable and the file should be saved in my folder called "/files". The location for the file should be in a variable like `$location =("/location")`.

Now my output is  generating in the root folder.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `client_details` ORDER BY `c_id` DESC LIMIT 1");  

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql))   
{ 
    $name=$data['name'];
}

$name_p = $name."-estimation.pdf";
$mpdf->Output($name_p,'F');
```

Comment: The same way you define any file path in PHP.

Comment: some more detailed description added kindly check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mpdf->Output("/absolute/path/to/directory/" . $name_p,'F');
```

or

```
$mpdf->Output("relative/path/to/directory/" . $name_p,'F');
```

Comment: what is absolute and relative path??? i did'nt get you bro, am sorry am new to php

Comment: $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `client_details` ORDER BY `c_id` DESC LIMIT 1");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$name=$data['name'];
}


$name_p = $name."-estimation.pdf";
$mpdf->Output("temp/" . $name_p,'F');

this is the current code

Comment: Thanks it worked man the second one , there is one more doubt can i give $variable as "relative/path/to/directory" that is like $mpdf->Output("$location" . $name_p,'F');

Comment: Yes if you want to assign the path to a variable you can, but don't _need_ the `" "` in the second part it would just be `$mpdf->Output($location . $name_p,'F')`

Comment: My folder name is in a variable called $F how can i place the variable name dynamically to the path section that is suppose my variable $F having folder name called "users" so i need to place the $F instead of writing directory name?? is that possible??

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = __DIR__.'/../../files/'; //til you're at the location of upload 
/*
//you can use, will return false if incorrect path
die(realpath($path to make sure you are at the right level))
*/
//concatenate file path to your file name 
$mpdf->Output($path.$name_p,'F');
```